# Skip api calls as a result of form submits until first api calls emits a value

Tags: angular, rxjs

To create an entity a user submits a form. He consecutively clicks the submit button multiple times, which results in the creation of multiple identical entities. We want to prevent that. How can we do that?

So obviously we can introduce a loading flag, that will be set to false initially and set to true whenever an api call is made. Using this flag we can disable the submit button.

However I was looking for another more functional approach, maybe using [**skipUntil**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skipuntil.html) operator:

> Skip emitted values from source until provided observable emits.

So first we have a stream of submit events. The submit events should be skipped if there is an update in progress. What I've tried:

```
// form reference
@ViewChild('form') form;
// reference to update observable
update$: Observable<any> ;

ngOnInit() {
    Observable.fromEvent(this.form.nativeElement, 'submit')
        .do(() => {
            // get values from form
        })
        .skipUntil(this.update$)
        .mergeMap(() => {
            this.update$ = this.datasource.update(..);
            return this.update$;
        })
        .subscribe()
}
```

As you can see I am in some kind of dilemma here. `this.update$` is defined later in the sequence. So following error is thrown:

```
You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `skipUntil` is not a good choice here because it would skip everything until `this.update$` emits inside `mergeMap()`. But that happens after `skipUntil` which still ignores everything so `mergeMap()` will never be invoked.

Instead you can use [`throttle`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttle) and trigger it with a subject:

```
const subject = new Subject();

Observable.fromEvent(this.form.nativeElement, 'submit')
    .do(() => {
        // get values from form
    })
    .throttle(subject)
    .mergeMap(() => {
        this.update$ = this.datasource.update(..).do(subject);
        // maybe it makes more sense to trigger `subject` in the subscribe callback instead of here.
        return this.update$;
    })
    .subscribe()
```

Comment: What would be the difference with `.throttle(this.datasource.update(..))`? (Since the return of `mergeMap()` is never used).

Comment: I suppose the correct syntax in previous comment should be `.throttle(() => this.datasource.update(..))` since throttle takes a selector function not an observable.